# Is my solution good enough to ensure the requests to my API come from my own website/mobile?

Tags: api

I am building an API that is going to be used by a partner's website. The website will be in the same domain (api.example.com and www.example.com). In the future we might have a mobile app that will consume this API.

I would not like to have someone using my api for their own website/app. So I would like to have a way to validate my website to my API.
I've searched in SO and found out that I would have to set a Cookie in my website so I send it every ajax request. Fair enough, but how would I generate this cookie? If I call a method in my API, I would have to validate it's origin, so it wouldn't solve.

I could set an encryption key on both sides and encrypt some information with a salt and send to the api to check the information.
I am not a security expert, but it seems it would solve my issue. Is this correct?
When a user logs into my website, would it be safe to change this validation with the user's login token?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your describing is called a CSRF (Cross Site Forgery Request).

To prevent someone from accessing your API's from outside your request, your website should store a token within the session, pass this token for every API request, then the API should validate the token.

There is a ton of good articles on the subject, including many specific examples.

Here is one of them [preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries](http://www.sitepoint.com/preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is: my API is completely decouple from the website. How can I store this information in a way my API is able to validate? Doing the way I said (having a key to encrypt some info with a salt in the website and having the key to decrypt it in the API) would solve the issue?

Comment: If they are completely decoupled, your API needs to ability to generate keys from trusted sources. You might want to expose another API method to generate public keys from a secret key (alternatively just have a list of whitelisted hosts that may request the token), then pass the public key for all subsequent requests. 

There are a ton of ways to accomplish this, but I would need more information on what your security expectations are and performance scalability.

Comment: I don't have high security expectations, my service does not have any sensitive data, but I just don't want people messing around with my API. Maybe I will use a public key encryption-like mechanism. Where I "sign" the request and verify it on the API. It is much simpler than generating keys from trusted sources and so on, but I think this would be enough for this point in time. Another option is have a symmetric key that would encrypt the a value to validate the request.

Comment: If your security expectations are low, an symmetric key is a good choice. Good luck!